# Autofill doesn't work with AppCompatEditText

Tags: android

I prepare my app for **Android O** support and want to make auto-fill work correctly. I selected **Google Auto-fill** service in System Settings, added special hints for auto-fill.

I have Sign-in `dialog` extends `DialogFragment`.
As wrote in Android developer, I don't need any movements to make auto-fill work, it will work automatically excepts addition to layout "`android:autofillHints`" and "`android:importantForAutofill`".

But autofill doesn't work.

Dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAutofill="yes"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="21dp"
        android:paddingRight="21dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            style="@style/LoginDialogTextTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button.text.enter" />

        <com.myapp.android.views.widgets.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_text_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:hint="@string/label.email"

            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/text_email"
                style="@style/EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/_gray_text"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" />
        </com.myapp.android.views.widgets.TextInputLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.myapp.android.views.widgets.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_text_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint.password"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_password"
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:autofillHints="password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingRight="100dp"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/_gray_text"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"


                    />
            </com.myapp.android.views.widgets.TextInputLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/button_show_password"
                style="@style/TextLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/show" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button_enter"
            style="@style/ButtonBig"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/button.text.enter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_restore"
            style="@style/TextLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:text="@string/button.text.forget_password" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            style="@style/ButtonDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @alexander-shtanko did you get it to work? I also have the same issue. logcat hints that something might be wrong with a credential, which makes little sense considering this is a system service and not play services.

Comment: Same issue here. Any success lately?